# R dplyr Elements within list in another list

Tags: r, dplyr

I need to find elements within list in another list, and then do things if elements are found.
If I have:

```
parents                             cluster genes
GO:0006928, GO:0006935, GO:0048812  Endo    a,b,c
GO:0006928, GO:0006935, GO:0048812  UE-Tip  h,s,y,z
GO:0006928, GO:0032879, GO:0050794  Endo    a,b,c,d,e,f
GO:0006928, GO:0040011, GO:0051674  Endo    h,j,k
GO:0006928, GO:0040011, GO:0051674  Immune  a,b,c,d,e,f
GO:0006928, GO:0040011, GO:0051674  N-NP    h,a,s,z
GO:0016431, GO:0052150, GO:0017431  Endo    z1,p4,z2
GO:0006928, GO:0040011, GO:0051674  N-Pod   q,w,r
GO:0016431, GO:0051152, GO:0016471  Endo    y,p,z2
```

For each "cluster", I want to find if any of the "parents" elements match any of the other "parents" elements. Then return the most common element and generate a union between "genes" for this element.

**For example:**

For "Endo", there would be 2 results. For 3 of the Endo "cluster", most common of the "parents" is GO:0006928, and "genes" would be "a,b,c,d,e,f,h,j,k". For the other, it is GO:0016431, and genes "z1,p4,z2,y,p"

It's a little complicated. If the above is a data.table called "big_data", I'm embarrassed to say that I've only gotten as far as:

```
big_data %>% 
   filter(cluster == "Endo")
```

It's comparing elements within a list within another list within a column ('parents') that's really got me stumped, and then returning the common item in the list, and doing the intersection of 'genes'.

Can someone please help?

[[edit: While this case shows 3 elements per "parents" list, there are cases where "parents" lists only contain 1 or 2 elements.]]

Answer (score 1):

Split the parents column into three separate columns. Create a list that contains the information you want.

We no longer split the parents column into three separate columns because the number of entries can be of varying lengths.

```
text="parents                             cluster genes
'GO:0006928'  Endo    a,b,c
'GO:0006928, GO:0006935, GO:0048812'  UE-Tip  h,s,y,z
'GO:0006928, GO:0032879'  Endo    a,b,c,d,e,f
'GO:0006928, GO:0040011, GO:0051674'  Endo    h,j,k
'GO:0006928, GO:0040011, GO:0051674'  Immune  a,b,c,d,e,f
'GO:0006928, GO:0040011, GO:0051674'  N-NP    h,a,s,z
'GO:0016431, GO:0052150, GO:0017431'  Endo    z1,p4,z2
'GO:0006928, GO:0040011, GO:0051674'  N-Pod   q,w,r
'GO:0016431, GO:0051152, GO:0016471'  Endo    y,p,z2"
dt=read.table(text=text, header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
dt=dt %>%
  filter(cluster=="Endo")
get_dt=function(dt) {
  my_list=list(list(unlist(str_split(dt$genes[1], ",")), str_trim(unlist(str_split(dt$parents[1], ",")))))
  if (nrow(dt)==1) {
    my_list[[1]][[2]]=names(sort(table(my_list[[1]][[2]]), decreasing=TRUE)[1])
    return(my_list)
  }
  for (i in 2:nrow(dt)) {
    parents=str_trim(unlist(str_split(dt$parents[i], ",")))
    letters=str_split(dt$genes[i], ",")[[1]]
    bool=TRUE
    for (j in 1:length(my_list)) {
      if (length(intersect(my_list[[j]][[2]], parents)) > 0) {
        my_list[[j]][[1]]=union(my_list[[j]][[1]], letters)
        my_list[[j]][[2]]=c(my_list[[j]][[2]], parents)
        bool=FALSE
        break
      }
    }
    if (bool) {
      my_list[[length(my_list)+1]]=list(letters, parents)
    }
  }
  for (i in 1:length(my_list)) {
    my_list[[i]][[2]]=names(sort(table(my_list[[i]][[2]]), decreasing=TRUE)[1])
  }
  return(my_list)
}
get_dt(dt)

[[1]]
[[1]][[1]]
[1] "a" "b" "c" "d" "e" "f" "h" "j" "k"

[[1]][[2]]
[1] "GO:0006928"


[[2]]
[[2]][[1]]
[1] "z1" "p4" "z2" "y"  "p" 

[[2]][[2]]
[1] "GO:0016431"
```

Comment: Consider Tidyr separate_rows function. It might be a better option than your lapply construct .

Comment: Wow, thanks so much! How will this behave if there are only 2 or 1 items in the parents  rows though? (I didn't have it in my example, which is probably bad).

Comment: It will behave well now that I've changed it.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a possible alternative.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

#convert data to long
long <- separate_rows(dt, parents, sep=", ")

#group by parents & clusters and count parents and summarize the common genes
#then filter when there are at least duplicate parents
combine <- long %>% group_by(parents, cluster) %>% 
                 summarize(count=n(), genes=paste(genes, collapse = ",")) %>% 
                 filter(count>1)

#Remove duplicates to clean up the genes
stringlist <-strsplit(combine$genes, ",") 
combine$genes <-sapply(stringlist, function(s){
   unique(s) %>% paste(collapse = ",")
})

combine
# A tibble: 2 x 4
# Groups:   parents [2]
  parents    cluster count genes            
  <chr>      <chr>   <int> <chr>            
1 GO:0006928 Endo        3 a,b,c,d,e,f,h,j,k
2 GO:0016431 Endo        2 z1,p4,z2,y,p
```